# How to move project to another org or space

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops

I have a project with DevOps support (git) and I want to be able to move it to another space.

I've seen postings on how to do it without DevOps support, but not sure if I can do it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With DevOps services you can move the app to a different space.
  You can do this by editing your pipeline.

1. Click on Build & Deploy for your project
2. Click the cog for your Deploy Stage
3. Click on "Configure Stage"
4. On this page you can change the space and the organization for the deployment
5. Choose your new settings
6. Click Save
7. Trigger the pipeline

Comment: That didn't work. It does show the correct space in the options, but triggering the pipeline did not move it. My new space is still empty.

Comment: Do you have a link to your git repo so i can heck it out?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using DevOps Services to change the space from the project settings?

1. On the project's Overview page, click the **Settings** icon. [Location of project settings icon.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUa7k.png)
2. Click **OPTIONS**.
3. In the Make this a Bluemix Project section, change the selected space to your new one.
4. Click **SAVE**.